# Resized Boot Camp partition from within Windows - Mac HDD with OS X is no longer bootable

Tags: bootcamp, startup, partition, ntfs

I decided to Resize my Boot Camp partition so I freed up 100GB from OS X and **used EaseUS to "merge" my C:\ drive on Windows with that 100GB floating space** (yes it was a mistake..)

Upon restarting, Windows gave me the blue screen, so I turned off/on the laptop and tried to boot into OS X again (Opt), Mac HDD partition no longer exists…

I didn't backup my Mac HDD for 2 months and I have extremely important work-related data that would be lost (another mistake).

Note: I need to recover Data on my Desktop, no interest in having OSX back, taking into consideration that FileVault was turned on (Mac HDD Encrypted).

- MacBook Pro 15" / 500GB PCIe (SSD)
- Mac OS: High Sierra Beta (400GB)
- Boot Camp: Windows 10 Pro (100GB)

Comment: You broke the golden rule - never allow windows anywhere near the partitioning; it just doesn't understand how it's fooled into thinking it's in charge.

Comment: @Tetsujin we all learn from our own mistakes.. I'm hoping some Tech savvy out there is able to help me find a fix.

Comment: I'm trying to find a canonical answer to this issue - it does crop up rather frequently...